# Invoke a method from Loaded Dll in which its parameter is of type interface C#

Tags: c#, dll, parameters, interface

I try to invoke my function invoked from loaded Dll in which it has an interface type as a parameter.
However, each time I get the same error: `System.ArgumentException`.

Briefly, my function is of signature: `public IResponse ProcessCommand(ICommand Command)` in which it accepts the `ICommand` interface as a parameter and returns the `IResponse` interface as returned value.

I have imported the Interface file in which we find definitions of both Interfaces `ICommand` and
`IResponse` to be used in my Application.

In the other side (Application):

```
        Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyFile.dll");
        Type Type = Assembly.GetType("MyFile.CommandHandler");
        var MethodInfo = Type.GetMethod("ProcessCommand");
        if(MethodInfo == null)
        {
           // Do some stuffs and then return an error
        }

        ICommand command = new GetModel_Command();

     
        object[] Params = new object[]{command};
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type);
        var result = MethodInfo.Invoke(instance,Params)
```

The line :  `ICommand command = GetModel_Command();` instanciate the class `GetModel_Command` that inherits from abstract class called `Command` that implements `ICommand` interface.

However, the error obtained when invoking the method  `ProcessCommand` says: `'Unable to convert an object of type' GetModel Command 'to type' MyFile.ICommand`.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `ICommand command = new GetModel_Command();` (with new keyword)? Is the class implementing a different ICommand than MyFile.ICommand? (I.e. from a different namespace?)

Comment: @ this why I have imported the Interface file in which we find definitions of both Interfaces `ICommand` and `IResponse` to be used in my Application.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have imported the Interface file'? You added a copy of it from your dll project? If so, this wouldn't work.

Comment: @Steeeve, I have imported the file `Interfaces.cs` from the DLL project.

Comment: That means, you have two projects with which each contain an ICommand interface. They have the same name, but they are declared by two different assemblies. Your `ProcessCommand` needs the interface defined by your dll. So if you would like to get this work, you will have to move your interface to a second dll which will be referenced by both of your existing projects.

Comment: @Steeeve, Thank you for your help, could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can validate it. I have created a library containing my shared Interface. However, I have another question that is a bit different from my main question. How can I import the signature of my class methods, in C++ we have Header files. In order to let the user knows the signature of each class method I want him to use it.